# Can sendmail be configured to allow bare line feeds?

Tags: email-server, sendmail

sendmail 8.14.4 / centos 5.x

I have an older relay running sendmail 8.14.4 and occasionally our organization will get emails with bare line feeds which are rejected by sendmail.

I understand that sendmail is doing this because the message is in violation of RFC 5321 section 4.1.1.4 which states:

```
   The custom of accepting lines ending only in LF, as a concession to
   non-conforming behavior on the part of some UNIX systems, has proven
   to cause more interoperability problems than it solves, and SMTP
   server systems MUST NOT do this, even in the name of improved
   robustness.  In particular, the sequence "LF.LF" (bare line
   feeds, without carriage returns) MUST NOT be treated as equivalent to
   CRLF.CRLF as the end of mail data indication.
```

However my management want to see if anything else can be done and I've noticed that other vendors like Microsoft have options to allow it (for example the `Set-ReceiveConnector` cmdlet with `-BareLinefeedRejectionEnabled` boolean value as noted [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/mail-flow/Set-ReceiveConnector?view=exchange-ps).

Does sendmail have a similar option? Or is it a hard-coded stance/rejection?

Comment: Could you post the bounce message generated and the relevant log entries? [Is it sendmail itself or some anti-spam add-on?]